# Weird equality issue with Generics and Enums?

Tags: vb.net, generics, enums

I'm kind of going nuts here.  I have a function something like the following.  It's failing to return an object.  I can pass in a list, I can see in `QuickWatch` that `x.RB = theRb` for at least one of the items in the list, yet it doesn't exit the loop (via the Return).  The loop continues.

The list I am passing in is a subclass of `aXXX`.

Property `RB` on class `aXXX` is of type `RBEnum`.

Also, I originally used Linq for this but was getting "no matching items" exceptions.

```vb
Private Shared Function GetX(Of T As aXXX)(ByVal a As List(Of T), 
 ByVal theRb As RBEnum) As T

    For Each x As T In a
        If (x.RB = theRb) Then Return x
    Next

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

Any suggestions or ideas on why this isn't working?

Comment: +1 for the `Im kind of going nuts here`, you aren't the only one...when is it friday?

Comment: How do you know they are "equal"? What type are they?

Comment: I check the value of x.RB and theRb in QuickWatch.  Both show the same value.  I show the value of x.RB = theRB in QuickWatch.  It shows True.  Is there anything else I can test beyond that?

Comment: What is the default equality comparer for the type; does it compare the values, or does it perform a reference-equals, checking whether they are the same instance?

Comment: The type? Both the property and the function parameter are defined "As RBEnum" where RBEnum is just an Enum.  I didn't explicitly code anything to compare the Enum.

Comment: I'm using Function(x) x.RB = theRB inside a Where clause in Linq elsewhere in code.  That code works fine.  (And for some reason the same query didn't work here which is why I resorted to the For Each.)

Comment: @Mike: Instead of using Where in this function you might try using Any with the same predicate. That should produce the boolean result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolution.  I can't fully explain it though.

The list of items I'm passing in are a subclass of the class aXXX.  The subclass did not properly override the `RB` property from the base class -- no `Overloads` / `Overrides` / `Shadows`.  This *kind of* gives explanation as to why QuickWatch reports True on the match -- maybe this subclass property was hiding the "real" property value that was in the test?

Anyway, by taking out the property in the subclass all together or adding an `Overloads`, the For Each behaves as one would expect.  I can even go back to the original Linq version I had in the function.

I guess this came down to oversight / sloppy coding on my part.  But the issue was masked pretty well by the fact that QuickWatch reported "false positives"!

Thanks to everyone for the suggestions and help.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying:

```
If (x.RB.Equals(theRb)) Then Return x
```

Comment: I agree, the `=` operator may not work as expected with generics.

Comment: Thanks... nice suggestion.  They're equal for the item in question and yet no Returning.  No dice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you cast the Enum into an Integer and then compare?

```
If CInt(x.RB)=CInt(theRb) Then Return x
```

Comment: Good idea.  I get 1 for both sides but doesn't move to the Return.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your original where statement was written but this should produce the result you're looking for:

```
Private Shared Function GetX(Of T As aXXX)(ByVal a As List(Of T), 
 ByVal theRb As RBEnum) As T

    Return a.Where(Function(x) x.RB = theRb).FirstOrDefault()

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is similar to the Linq query I had originally.  I know you're pointing out that I could use the "OrDefault" part.  However, the current case is that there _is_ a match.

I replaced the Linq query with a For Each so I could inspect the values as it iterated.